# IE11 scroll stuttering on overriding default keydown scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

**EDIT: I'm remaking the whole question.**

The context to the problem is more complex but, for the sake of simplification, **let's say I want to override some of the default scrolling animations**.

For that purpose, I create a function- filterKeys()- that filters the 'scrolling keys' (PgUp, PgDn, up and down arrows, etc.). I'll leave you a piece of code with the function (as I said the context is more complex).

```
// Determines what type of scroll will be done depending on the key pressed.
    function filterKeys(e) {
        // If there's already a key associated with a scrolling animation pressed, or there's an animation running: return without doing anything.
        if (isPressed || isRunning)
            return;

        var keyMatch = false; // It will only call any function if the key pressed matches one of the key codes in the array.
        $.each(keyCodes, function (index, value) {
            if (e.which == keyCodes[index]) {
                keyMatch = true;
                return false; // It's tantamount to a break statement on a regular loop.
            }
        });

        if (keyMatch) {
            e.preventDefault();
            currentKey = e.which;

            switch (e.which) {
            case 40: // Down arrow key.
                animateRegularScroll(e, 'down', 190);
                break;
            case 38: // Up arrow key.
                animateRegularScroll(e, 'up', 190);
                break;
            case 34: // PgDn key.
                animatePageScroll(e, 'down', 190);
                break;
            case 33: // PgUp key.
                animatePageScroll(e, 'up', 190);
                break;
            case 35: // End key.
                animateFullScroll(e, 'down');
                break;
            case 36: // Home key.
                animateFullScroll(e, 'up');
                break;
            case 1: // Primary mouse button.
                if ($(this).hasClass('bottom') || $(this).hasClass('top'))
                    animateRegularScroll(e, $(this).hasClass('bottom') ? 'down' : 'up', 190);
                break;
            case 2: // Middle mouse button.
                animateMMScroll(e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Now, the animations will go smooth except for the one where you have to maintain the up or down arrow keys pressed. That one will stutter in IE11.**

A simplified fiddle (it's not well done, there's a lot of stuff missing but it serves the purpose): https://jsfiddle.net/LLu0esue/15/ .
Try with IE11 and you'll see the stutter. Try it with Chrome or Firefox and it will go smoothly.

The thing is if I put e.preventDefault() in the first line of filterKeys(), it will go smoothly on IE11 too. (the same fiddle as before but with e.preventDefault() at the beginning: https://jsfiddle.net/LLu0esue/17/).

Obviously that behaviour is undesirable because that way I would prevent Ctrl + T from opening a new tab, F5 from refreshing, etc. I do not want that.

Any ideas as to why IE11 is behaving this way?

Comment: Why don't you use `e.preventDefault();` inside your `animateRegularScroll` function? You're passing anyways the `e` event argument

Comment: Also it would be interesting to know on which **key event** you're calling your function and how you're dealing with `isPressed` since clearly that's one of your issues.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tried that too but wouldn't work either. The reason I prefer to put it here is because I only need to write it once. While the other way around I'd need to write that statement for each type of animation. EDIT: I'll add the event (it's inside a addListeners function but I'll write the line).

Comment: No, you don't need to. localize in your code the `animateRegularScroll` function and inside it you can place your  `preventDefault` **once**.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sorry Roko, I think I'm not understanding you. I've got different animations: animateRegular, animatePage, animateFull, etc. Writting e.preventDefault() inside them would mean writing it more than once, whereas writting it inside filterKeys means writting it only once. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Ahh yes, I get it, anyways, I was just chattering, the way you're doing it seems already OK, since you're `e.preventDefault()`-ing it only *if* `keyMatch`. But seems that you're having issues with the function triggered by *repeated keystrokes on hold*. Therefore the code you provided is not enough I think to resolve your issue. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'll try to do that. Maybe reproduce it on codepen or something.

Comment: Yes! [jsbin.com](//jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle.net](//jsfiddle.net) would be awesome.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan done!